# About ImageTextButton And TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, libgdx

I want to change TextView to ImageTextButton.

This is the sample code I have used for the program.

---

```
TextView test1, test2;

public void changeTurn() { 

   if (turn == 0) {
      turn = 1;

      test1.setClickable(false);
      test2.setClickable(true);

   }

   else {

      turn = 0;

      test1.setClickable(true);
      test2.setClickable(false);

   }
}
```

---

The question is, I don't want to use TextView and want to change it to ImageTextButton that can do the same as the sample code above. I mean it is like I can set the ImageTextButton to be clickable or not in my if statement.

Comment: What's an ImageTextButton?! I never heard of a control with that name.

Comment: Sorry, there has no such view as `ImageTextButton` in android.

Comment: Seems as though he just wants to make a clickable TextView

Comment: Sorry my bad. I got it functioning now. :)

Comment: Its a LibGDX function. Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

By "ImageTextButton" I assume you mean [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

So the answer

> The question is, I don't want to use TextView and want to change it to ImageTextButton that can do the same as the sample code above

is yes. It `extends` [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) so you can set it to [clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable)

FYI: All of those links lead to somewhere in the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got it function. Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using LibGDX. I use setTouchable(Touchable.enabled) and setTouchable(Touchable.disabled).